# UICollectionView registerCell - Blank Cells

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

I've just starting playing around with UICollectionView for the first time. Seems to work nicely, but having an issue and a question about it.

I have my UICollectionView setup as below and with a custom cell:

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)view numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: (UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ContactCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.nameLbl.text = @"text";

    return cell;
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(145, 95);
}

- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
}
```

So this is all dandy, however I have added this line to `viewDidLoad`:

```
[collectionView registerClass:[ContactCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

This is causing trouble and I don't understand why. When I enable this line, all of my cells go blank. How come? What am I missing?

Also, as I understand it, if that line enables reusable cells, why do I have to with a collection view vs not having to in a table view?

Comment: how are you setting up the view for the cell? programmatically in your subclass?

Comment: I have set it up in my Storyboard. I have a UICollectionView with a single cell, that cell has its identifier, custom class hooked up and label in it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You storyboard is automatically registering the cell you designed in the storyboard for the reuse identifier you specified  for that cell in the right hand pane in interface builder. By re-registering your class for that reuse identifier the collection view simply calls alloc init on your subclass and expects the view to be setup programmatically.

From [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> If you previously registered a class or nib file with the same reuse
>   identifier, the class you specify in the cellClass parameter replaces
>   the old entry. You may specify nil for cellClass if you want to
>   unregister the class from the specified reuse identifier.

If you want to design cells **outside of the storyboard** you can either setup your interface programmatically or set up a cell in a seperate xib and then call

`- (void)registerNib:(UINib *)nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier`

Where the nib must have one top level view which is a cell of your custom subclass with the right reuse identifier set in interface builder.

Comment: So your saying I can only visually design my cell from a xib and use the method you suggest, otherwise I must create it programmatically?

Comment: or you can design them in the storyboard by adding prototype cells to the collection view. the story board registers that cell automatically for you and reuse is turned on.

Comment: thats why it goes blank when you call `registerClass:`, you're unsetting the stuff you did in the storyboard. Its also why it works without the line. Collection views wont function without some sort of reusable cell specified

Comment: Ok, I'm happy designing them in storyboard and have done so. But Im confused as to why, when calling `registerClass' method, sure, its makes them reusable so blanks out my cells. But why do I not see the "text" label that I set? If I clear my cells, where am I supposed to populate them?

Comment: it doesnt make them reusable as opposed to not being reusable, they were always reusable anyway. The reason they go blank is that nowhere in your class do you add the label as a subview. That was done in the reusable cell set in the storyboard.

Comment: what it comes down to is you do not need to call `registerClass:` because it has already been called for you by the storyboard.

Comment: Oh right, well thats far more sense now, thanks. So at its core, the need to call that is purely based upon my approach? Whether I want to design in my Storyboard or take a more programatic approach, right?

Comment: Yes when designing reusable cells in a storyboard you do not need to call this method because the storyboard takes care of it for you. All cells are reusable. The method is there for those that wish to design their cells in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

Remove

```
[self.collectionview registerClass:[NewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

For storyboards we don't need this line

Comment: Yes the is the Answer √