# Using Autolayout constraints from Storyboard in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a custom `UICollectionViewCell` class for my `UICollectionView`. I have to use addSubview in my custom class because I'm using FirebaseUI-iOS. This is what my MessageCollectionViewCell looks like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
class MessageCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var messageContainerView: UIView?
    @IBOutlet var messageText: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var messageDisplayName: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var messageUserImage: UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var messageUserImageOverlay: UIView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // Custom initialization code for label
        let size = self.contentView.frame.size
        let frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, size.width, size.height)

        self.messageContainerView = UIView(frame: frame)
        self.messageUserImageOverlay = UIView(frame: frame)
        self.messageText = UILabel(frame: frame)
        self.messageDisplayName = UILabel(frame: frame)

        self.messageContainerView!.addSubview(self.messageUserImageOverlay!)
        self.messageContainerView!.addSubview(self.messageText!)
        self.messageContainerView!.addSubview(self.messageDisplayName!)
        self.contentView.addSubview(messageContainerView!)
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        println("Init")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

I have constraints in my Storyboard file which I want to use, but when I'm using addSubview my constraints does not get used. Is there anyway I can use addSubview() and still keep the constraints? I know that I can add it programmatically, but I wish to use the constraints that i've already set inside Storyboard.

Comment: Looks like it's related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13224090/uicollectionview-registercell-blank-cells. Looks like https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI/Implementation/FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource.m#L77 causes an overwrite of the prototype cell. You can also use the XIB constructor for FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource and still have a custom class. This should pull in constraints from the XIB and autolayout, which is more robust than doing prototype cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is due to how FirebaseUI 'FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource` registers it's classes. I don't believe it's possible to instantiate a class like this and get the autolayout properties from a XIB like you're asking, but it is possible to solve the problem a layer back by fixing our handling of prototype cells.

The problem here is that we're registering the cell reuseIdentifier twice: once in the storyboard and once in code (`FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource` must do this in order to dequeue cells). Since we call ours second, it overwrites the first one, which means that none of your outlets are populated, layouts are weird, etc. This means that you have to set them up as if you were using regular subclasses rather than XIBs. The quickest thing you could do here is just use a XIB instead of a prototype cell (which is just a XIB inside the storyboard). So, how can we support FirebaseUI + prototype cells...

The short answer is that currently this feature isn't possible due to Apple's design of `UICollectionView`.

Unlike `UITableView`, which can check for this behavior by dequeuing a cell (which would return an instantiated prototype cell and tell us that the reuseidentifier has already been created) like we do in `FirebaseTableViewDataSource` [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI/Implementation/FirebaseTableViewDataSource.m#L77-L79), `UICollectionView` doesn't provide a similar method, it only gives:

```
func dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(_ identifier: String,
                           forIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> AnyObject
```

Given that this method requires an a `indexPath` as it *has* to return a non-nil object, it will throw an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` when we try to read an arbitrary object at initialization (since there exist no items for it to read from). Additionally, there doesn't appear to be any way to programmatically check if a `reuseIdentifier` is in use. This leaves us with a few options:

1. Recommend people not use prototype cells and instead do custom subclasses or XIBs and hook them in. Storyboards and prototype cells feel a little more brittle (mostly for reasons like this), but definitely have ease of use going for them.
2. Pull the `-registerClass: forReuseIdentifier:` call out of `FirebaseCollectionViewDataSource`, though this means that `FirebaseTableViewDataSource` should be changed as well (even though it can work) and make the developer explicitly call this (or not in the case of using a Storyboard).
3. Add a parameter for storyboards to the initialization call which would still retain the `reuseIdentifier` to dequeue cells, but not register the class.
4. Try to dequeue a cell, catch the `NSException`, register the class and try again. This works, but it throws the exception still and adds a little more code in the runloop (we have to wrap the call with try-catch that we know will fail at most once).

My personal preference is 1, but the value proposition for prototype cells is high enough that 3 might be the best option for this library. I'd rather not do 2, since cell registration is a difficult enough problem.

For now, I'd recommend using XIBs instead of prototype cells, or waiting for us to pick one of the above solutions (we can push a release pretty quickly to solve the problem).